# How to send a form contained in a JSP page to a Servlet properly

Tags: jsp, servlets, http-status-code-404

I have this form declaration in my JSP page:

```
<form name="login" method="post" action="loginServlet">
```

Assume that the servlet is appropriately declared in the web.xml file; with this pattern `<url-pattern>/loginServlet</url-pattern>`;

this `servlet` contains a doPost method.

But what happens is that when I press the button associated to the login form, the server complains that this servlet is not found. What kind of path should I use in order to make it work?

This is the folder structure of my project:

```
-Project0
   -jsppages
      login.jsp
   +htmlpages
   -WEB-INF
      -classes 
          LogIn.class
```

I guess there's a problem with the path. How could I fix this. Thank you!

Edit: the web.xml contains exactly this referred to my servlet:

```
  <servlet>
      <servlet-name>LogInServlet</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>LogIn.class</servlet-class>
   </servlet>

   <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>LogInServlet</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/loginServlet</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
```

SOLVED:

When calling the action releted to the form, it was necessary to go out of the JSP folder in my project folder by using the path ../loginsServlet so it becomes like this.

```
<form name="login" method="post" action="../loginServlet">
```

Comment: Is it a typo, or is it really written </rule-pattern> in your file ?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs92/webapp/configureservlet.html Look at this too. Your web.xml file is incomplete if you only use the line given in your question

Comment: `<url-pattern>/loginServlet</rule-pattern> ` < - This is not valid XML

Comment: Read something about web.xml

Comment: <url-pattern>/loginServlet</url-pattern>  Check the link I just gave

Answer (score 0):

check your `web.xml` which is present in `WEB-INF` directory

below is sample

```
<web-app>
<display-name>HelloWorld Application</display-name>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>HelloServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>SERVLET CLASS NAME WITH PACKE</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>HelloServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/loginServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

and change your action value

```
<form name="login" method="post" action="./loginServlet">
```

Answer (score 0):

add this to your `web.xml` file . your page will map to your `Servlet`

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>loginservlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>package.LogIn</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>loginservlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/loginServlet</url-pattern>
```

> **Note**:- Please Put the complete package name (eg `com.login.ClassName`) before your class name.

Thank You